# Change REST Method Response XML Node name in MVC 4

Tags: c#, rest, xml-serialization, asp.net-mvc-4

We are building a REST Service using MVC4 and added method like:

```
    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContacts()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }
```

The response of this method in XML generated as:

```
<ArrayOfContact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Contact>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Name>Alice</Name>
    <Email>alice@example.com</Email>
  </Contact>
  <Contact>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <Email>bob@example.com</Email>
  </Contact>
  <Contact>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <Name>Charles</Name>
    <Email>charles@example.com</Email>
  </Contact>
</ArrayOfContact>
```

I would like to change the tag <ArrayOfContact> to <Contacts>.
I know if it would be a property of a class then we could add attributes to the property to change it.

But is it possible to change the Root Node of Response?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to fix it with the creation of a classe Contacts.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "a namespace",Name="Contacts")]
public class Contacts
{
    private List<Contact> contacts= null;
    [DataMember]
    public List<Contact> Contacts
    {
        get
        {
            if (contacts == null)
            {
                contacts = new List<Contact>();
            }
            return contacts;
        }
        set
        {
            contacts= value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you will get an XML with the wanted header.

Comment: It will generate XML like `<Contacts> <Contacts><Contact> ... </Contact></Contacts> </Contacts>`  which is not correct response.

Comment: if you add [DataContract(Namespace = "a namespace",Name="Contacts")] at the top of your contact class ? will it help? (without creationg a new class)